# Facebook Like Button

Tags: javascript, css, facebook

Is there a way to change the text next to the Facebook Like button to white, instead of the "#808080" color it is set to?

Comment: Most likely the answer is yes. Can you post the code/link? What like button are you using? There are all kinds of plugins/implementations.

Comment: Yes, could you post an image of the text? I'm not finding anything remotely close to the `Like` button with that color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you can change (on the text) is the colorscheme.  either 'light' or 'dark'.
You can change the background color of the iframe.  But not the text in CSS style... unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The class of the `Like` button is `like_link stat_elem as_link`, but I'm not seeing any `#808080` deceleration. I'll post some working code once I find it.